# Hover effects on list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my vertical navigation, I want to highlight list item which is last clicked and currently active. Highlighting is done with assigning red background to list item. I also want to highlight list item on mouse hover. Problem is when hovering on other list items, I want to temporarily remove class active from active list item, and when the mouse pointer is no longer on inactive list item, that active class is assigned to active list item back again. Here is what it looks like on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9r3tx/2/

This is jQuery function which assigns class active to list item which is clicked:

```
//Add class active on click, firts li is active by default
$('.navigation li:first').addClass('active');

$(".navigation li a").click(function(e) {
    $('.navigation li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

This is where problem is:

```
//Change classes on hover
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
$(".navigation li a").hover(function(e){
    $('.navigation li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
});
```

I know that this assigns class active to hovered link, and stays like that, but I want to temporarily assign class active, which would just last for time when the pointer is above that list.

Comment: Why don't you just use css for the hover state? `.navigation li:hover a {}`

Comment: If user wants jquery and only javascript and jquery were selected by user, use mouseleave. See my answer with working demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own suggestion would be to use CSS in concert with jQuery:

```
$('.navigation li:first').addClass('active');

$('.navigation li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

With the CSS:

```
/* overrides the red of the '.active' when the list is hovered:
*/
.navigation:hover li.active {
    background-color: #fff;
}

/*
sets the li.active colour,
ensures the colour of the li.active when it's hovered,
and colours the li elements when they're hovered:
*/
.navigation li.active,
.navigation li.active:hover,
.navigation li:hover {
    background:red;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9r3tx/5/).

Comment: That is really weird UX behavior.. what is it for?

Answer (score 0):

How about **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/9r3tx/13/)** simple demo which does exactly what you ask for using `mouseleave`

```
//Add class active on click, firts li is active by default
    $('.navigation li:first').addClass('active');

    $(".navigation li a").click(function(e) {
        $('.navigation li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }); 

//Change classes on hover
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $(".navigation li a").hover(function(e){
        $('.navigation li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });

    $(".navigation li a").on('mouseleave', function(e){ // this function for removing
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: but when mouse leaves li, none of the list item has the class active... hovering is done ok, but i want that previously clicked link is highlighted, when mouse leaves ul...

Comment: OK check new demo. Does exactly what you asked for using an extra CSS class

Comment: Or you could just pass the second function (for mouseleave) to hover instead of adding an additional, separate event.